# Zurb Foundation 4 & jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, zurb-foundation

Has anyone workout out how to add in jQuery UI to the standard Foundation 4 setup?

I have the standard index.html downloaded with the framework, but can not get jQuery UI to work with it... it looks like foundation has some of the functions I need show/hide but not slideDown() etc

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI is not included in the foundation package. The `$.show()` and `$.hide()` are part of the standard jQuery package and that is why they work for you. You just have to include the jQuery UI file in your application as usual.